# must declare scalar variable for @User_Id and for Activity

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

While I am execution the following procedure I get these errors:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@USer_Id".
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@Activity".

Can anybody help me how to fix these errors?

Here is the view creation is mandatory and the conditions are initially the view table data should be retrieved based upon the `User_Id`, given `Timestamp` rage i.e. `start_time` and `end_time` parameters and after getting the result, we have get the data based upon the Activity

The code which I wrote

```
create procedure Proc1 
    @User_Id varchar(50), 
    @start_time bigint,
    @end_time bigint,
    @view_name varchar(50),
    @Activity varchar(30)
as 
begin
    exec('create view view_name
          as 
             select 
                 Asset_Id, Activity, User_Id, Event_Description, Timestamp 
             from
                (SELECT 
                    [j30c_editorial_id] AS Asset_Id,
                    [j30c_action] As Activity,
                    [j30c_description] As Event_Description,
                    [j30c_user_name] As User_Id,
                    [j30c_date] As Timestamp
                 FROM 
                    [sandboxmbdb].[dbo].[j30t_changelog]

                 UNION ALL

                 SELECT 
                    [Asset_Id],
                    [j30c_action],
                    [Event_Type_Desc],
                    [User_Id],
                    [Timestamp] 
                 FROM 
                    [refauditdatabase].[dbo].[AS_Event_Tracker_T] a,
                    [refauditdatabase].[dbo].[AS_Event_Type_M] b 
                 WHERE 
                    a.[Event_Type_Id] = b.[Event_Type_Id]) aa
             where 
                 User_Id = @User_Id 
                 and Timestamp between @start_time and @end_time 
                 and view_name = @view_name')
    exec('select * from view_name where Activity = @Activity and view_name = @view_name')
end
```

Comment: Your query is built to return a resultset and create a view at the same time. Don't do that. Just execute the query and return the result.

Comment: thanks for what you said but the thing is i have to create a view and i have to retrive the data and i have to delete that view all the things in one query itself

Comment: If the requirement is that this procedure must create a view, query from it, then delete the view, then whoever wrote the requirement is very confused. If you've reinterpreted what the actual requirement is and you think that you need to solve it by creating a view, querying from it, then dropping it, then you are very confused. Whichever it is, what you're doing doesn't make sense. Stop what you're doing, go back to the requirements, and actually work out what *needs* to be done. Hint: the words "create a view" shouldn't appear there.